# C Pointers Segfaults

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a C project. The just of it is that we have a health vital reading program. I can add patients and add readings and remove patients. I have all the rest working, of which I'll link my code. I'm having a set fault that I've isolated in removePatient. I've tried gdb but for some reason it doesn't want to work with me today.

Here is the code in question:

```
void removePatient(int patientID) {
    int i, count;
    Chartptr patientsChart;
    Chartptr previousChart;
    Chartptr currentChart;
    CBuffptr healthTypeBuffer;
    CBuffptr allHealthTypeBuffers[MAXREADINGS];

    // if patient was found, remove the patient
    patientsChart = getChart(patientID);
    if (patientsChart != NULL) {
        healthTypeBuffer = patientsChart->buffer;

        if (healthTypeBuffer != NULL) {
            // gather all the heath type buffers
            count = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < MAXREADINGS || healthTypeBuffer != NULL; ++i) {
                allHealthTypeBuffers[i] = healthTypeBuffer;
                healthTypeBuffer = healthTypeBuffer->next;
                count++;
            }

            // free all the health type buffers
            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                free(allHealthTypeBuffers[i]);
            }
        }

        // find the chart before specified patient chart
        currentChart = patientList;
        while (currentChart != patientsChart) {
            previousChart = currentChart;
            currentChart = currentChart->next;
        }

        // reorganize list, then free patient chart
        previousChart->next = patientsChart->next;
        free(patientsChart);
    }
}
```

I believe I wrote the code to be fairly readable.

Here are some of the struct declarations that are used in the above code:

```
/* One health type reading: timestamp + actual value */
typedef struct{
    char timestamp[MAXTIME+1];
    int value;
}Element;

/* 
*   Health type readings: linked list of Circular buffers 
*/
typedef struct healthEntry* CBuffptr; /* pointer to a CircularBuffer */

typedef struct healthEntry{
    int type;              /* health data type (1-5) */
    int start;                 /* index of oldest reading */
    int end;               /* index of most current reading */
    Element reading[MAXREADINGS];  /* fixed array of readings */
    CBuffptr next;             /* pointer to next health type buffer */
}CircularBuffer;

/*
*   Patient's health chart: ID + linked list of  health type readings
*/
typedef struct chartEntry* Chartptr;   /* pointer to a Chart */

typedef struct chartEntry{
    int id;             /* patient ID */
    CBuffptr  buffer;       /* pointer to first health type buffer */
    Chartptr  next;         /* pointer to next patient */
}Chart;

/* global declaration for start of the patient chart linked list */
extern Chartptr patientList;
```

Comment: This is quite a bit of code.  Have you tried taking out parts and trying to replicate the problem with a subset of the code?  Have you been compiling from time to time as you write, and have some idea of when the bug was introduced?  This kind of info would help people help you -- and frankly, if you paid attention to that info, you might even be able to solve the problem yourself

Comment: Everything else works 100%. The only code that was added was the removePatient function.

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is very helpful.

Comment: The rest of the code at the bottom is for your reference, you don't need to look at its entirety.

Comment: I am noticing your `for` condition: `i < MAXREADINGS || healthTypeBuffer != NULL`.  That should probably be `&&`; otherwise, if `healthTypeBuffer` is null, you'll still try to use it if `i` is still within the array bounds.

Comment: cHao, God bless you man! You've solved my question! Thank you so so much!

Comment: TL;DR. That `Charptr` (and generally every pointer-related) typedef is very hard to read as well.

Answer (score 4):

While I didn't look through most of your code, the following line seems suspicious to me:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXREADINGS || healthTypeBuffer != NULL; ++i) {
```

I suspect that you want it to be:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXREADINGS && healthTypeBuffer != NULL; ++i) {
```

There may be other issues too, but I'm pretty sure that the logic above at least calls for `&&`.